# what's the version of hibernate and groovy when my spring-boot-starter upgrade to 3.0.0?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, groovy

i want to upgrade my project ,and the old version of spring-boot-starter is 2.4.8 , the old version of hibertate is 5.4.4.Final . I want use java 17 recently . Which versions should be upgraded

```
       <hibernate.version>5.4.4.Final</hibernate.version>
       <commons-codec.version>1.12</commons-codec.version>
       <commons-beanutils.version>1.9.3</commons-beanutils.version>
        <commons-pool2.version>2.6.1</commons-pool2.version>
        <commons-email.version>1.5</commons-email.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.8.1</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-net.version>3.6</commons-net.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
        <liquibase.version>3.6.2</liquibase.version>
        <protostuff.version>1.6.0</protostuff.version>
        <netty.version>4.1.34.Final</netty.version>
        <guava.version>27.1-jre</guava.version>
        <poi.version>4.1.0</poi.version>
        <easypoi.version>4.1.0.AGS</easypoi.version>
        <easyexcel.version>2.2.6</easyexcel.version>
        <quartz.version>2.3.1</quartz.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
        <shiro.version>1.5.1</shiro.version>
        <buji-pac4j.version>4.1.1</buji-pac4j.version>
        <pac4j.version>3.8.3</pac4j.version>
        <ehcache3.version>3.8.0</ehcache3.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.4.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <fastjson.version>2.0.6</fastjson.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.4.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <fastjson.version>2.0.6</fastjson.version>
        <!--override spring default dependency version -->
        <ldaptive.version>1.2.4</ldaptive.version>
        <springdoc-openapi.version>1.5.9</springdoc-openapi.version>
        <swagger-api.version>2.1.9</swagger-api.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.49</mysql.version>
        <sqlserver.version>4.0</sqlserver.version>
        <oracle.version>11.2.0.3</oracle.version>
        <freemark.version>2.3.30</freemark.version>
        <itextpdf.version>5.5.9</itextpdf.version>
        <itextpdf.xmlworker.version>5.5.9</itextpdf.xmlworker.version>
        <itext.asian.version>5.2.0</itext.asian.version>
        <itext.xhtmlrenderer.version>9.0.3</itext.xhtmlrenderer.version>
        <jasypt.version>2.1.2</jasypt.version>
        <groovy.version>4.0.12</groovy.version>
        <reflections.version>0.10.2</reflections.version>
```

Give me some suggestions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Spring Boot, you should let Spring Boot [manage the versions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.build-systems.dependency-management) of those dependencies, and not manage them yourself. You should only specify versions of dependencies which are not managed by Spring Boot (or in rare cases if you have an explicit and clear reason to deviate from the version managed by Spring Boot).

If you really want to manage this yourself (but you really, really shouldn't), you can find them listed in [Dependency Versions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions) in the [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/) (NOTE: this links to the latest Spring Boot, which at the moment is 3.1.1, but will update when a new versions is released).

Comment: i manage the version of JPA or MQ with the spring boot starter, however not all jars can managed by spring boot, like the version hibernate. How do I correctly find the dependent jar version that is not controlled by spring boot

Comment: @kimlerjin The version of Hibernate *is* managed by Spring Boot, but the coordinates of Hibernate changed with Hibernate 6. Make sure the dependencies you're importing use groupId `org.hibernate.orm` and not `org.hibernate` (which was used by Hibernate 5.x).

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel thank you for your answers.